# order of an integer related

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading a number theory text and this is when I encoutntered a line like this:
         "for $n=12$ , $\phi(12)=4$,  yet there is no integer that is of order $4$ modulo $12$; indeed we find that
   $$   1^1\equiv5^2\equiv7^2\equiv11^2\equiv1 \bmod{12}       $$

and therefore the only choice for orders is 1 or 2.
And, so for an arbitrarily selected divisor $d$ of $\phi(n)$, it is not always true that there exists an integer $a$ having order $d$ modulo $n$.
  And, what I'm wondering is how did the author conclude that $4$ cannot be the order of some integer modulo $12$,and why did he only try out the integers( like: 1,11,5,7) which were "less than" $12$ .
Can't $4$ be the order of some integer- greater than $12$ and also relatively prime to it.
The book I'm reading from hasn't mentioned anything like-in addition to $a$ and $n$ having gcd 1 , a should also be less than $n$.
Thanks in advance, to all.

Answer (score 1):

To define the multiplicative order of an integer mod $n$ it needs to be an element of the group of units to begin with - that is, it needs to be invertible - which requires $(a,n)=1$ (this is sufficient too).

If $L$ is the list of integers $1\le k\le n$ which are coprime to $n$, then $L$ traces out every possible residue class of units, that is every possible integer invertible mod $n$. Even if you pick an integer $>n$, mod $n$ it is the same as one of the $k$ in the list $L$. So we lose no information by just considering the elements of $L$.

In particular, notice the integers which are invertible mod $12~$ ($1,3,5,7,11,13,15,17,\cdots$) when reduced modulo $12$ simply give $1,3,5,7,11$ repeating over and over again. These are *all* of the invertible integers mod $12$, they exhaust them all. There are not any integers invertible mod $12$ that are not congruent to one of $1,3,5,7,11$.

The author concluded that no integer mod $12$ has order $4$ by showing every single invertible integer mod $12$ has order one or two, which precludes having order four.

Answer (score 0):

It is fruitful to think of modular arithmetic *not* as a fancy equivalence relation on the integers, but instead as its own number system. There are only twelve numbers in Mod-12 arithmetic. We can use integers to represent mod-12 numbers, but many different integers represent the same mod-12 number: e.g. $1$ and $13$ represent the same mod-12 number.

Only four of the mod-12 numbers are invertible, and so only four of the numbers need to be tested.